# Apache2 eating all the system RAM

Tags: linux, debian, cache, dell, free

I'm serving on Images ( JPG|JPEG|PNG ) from an apache server. after sometime, the system cache becomes sooo populated that no other programs are able to run -- like recently I noticed that one of the php Cronjob got terminated because of no memory available to process a  large number of files.

Can I configure apache2 in such a way that the images served aren't cached in RAM at all, and they should go directly form the storage subsystem. I know it will increase IO, but System will be able to perform other functions.

Secondly, as far as I know, these caches are circular in their operation. whenever there is need for some  RAM space, older ( LRU? ) objects are kicked out of the RAM and needy programs gets inserts. I'm not seeing it happening here.

Its a Debian-8 Linux System, running Dell-R320 with 24 Cores + 15GB RAM. all filled up sooner or later.

Comment: Isn't it improbable that the filesystem cache would be blocking processes from starting?  In your configuration I'd rather look at the number of running processes, and network connections that haven't been closed.  How much memory would the php job need (do you have a core dump)?

Comment: Yes, You are right... PHP memory exhausted because of allowed memory  limit of 256MB, which is working fine after increasing it to 512MB. My Query is to generally disable the apache's static content serving without caching it.

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing Apache can do about that.  There may be kernel parameters influencing the size of the filesystem cache.